# How to to place a picture/logo in a header with and without content already in it?

Tags: vba, ms-word, header

I currently work for a recruiting firm and I'm trying to write a program that will post my company's Logo on the Top Left Corner of a resume.

Some resumes have content in the header, some don't. I made two if's statements to address both circumstances, but for some odd reason, it does not seem to work.

This is my code below:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim FooterText As String
Dim Logo As Shape
Dim HeaderExists As Section

'Header:

ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader

Set HeaderExists = ActiveDocument.Sections(1)

Set Logo = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="My company logo", _
LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True).ConvertToShape

If HeaderExists.Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Exists = False Then
    With Logo
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
        .Left = -67
        .Top = -30
        .Width = 107
        .Height = 48
    End With
End If

If HeaderExists.Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Exists = True Then
    With Logo
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
        .Left = 5
        .Top = 5
        .Width = 107
        .Height = 48
    End With
End If
```

As of right, the code only works for resumes WITH content in the Header. For some reason, when I change `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` to `wdFooterFirstPage`, it flips, and only works for resumes WITHOUT content in the Header.

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? Please be specific as to what you expect and what's actually happening.

Comment: I want to add my company logo to the top left corner (preferably in the header) of any resume in the same place whether or not the resume has content in its header already. If there is content in the header, I want to keep the content as is, but still add my company's logo in the top left corner. If the resume does not have anything in its header, I still want to add the logo in the same place. @CindyMeister

Comment: Did macropod's answer not help? If not, you still haven't clarified how the code you show isn't working. Please describe *how* it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to logo to appear on every page, you'll need to apply a 'different first page' layout to documents that don't already have it. Then you'll need to decide what to do with documents that didn't have that layout but had a header, since the existing header will now only appear on the 2nd & subsequent pages (if there is more than one page). In the following code, I've enforced a 'different first page' layout, which obviates any concerns about what happens in your problem scenario, and have assumed the header & logo are only to appear on the first page:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Sctn As Section, Rng As Range, Shp As Shape
Set Sctn = ActiveDocument.Sections.First
With Sctn
  If .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False Then
    'Apply a Different First Page layout
    .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    Set Rng = .Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range
    With Rng
      'Replicate the original Primary header
      If Sctn.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text <> "" Then
        .FormattedText = Sctn.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.FormattedText
        .Characters.Last.Delete
      End If
    End With
    'Delete the original Primary header
    Sctn.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = vbNullString
  End If
  With Rng
    .Collapse wdCollapseStart
    'Add the logo
    Set Shp = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="My company logo", _
      LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True).ConvertToShape
    'Adjust the logo's formatting
    With Shp
      .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
      .Left = 5
      .Top = 5
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      .Width = 107
    End With
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If the document has multiple Sections, you'll also need to consider what to do with their page layouts & headers.